Import subset option is disabled in tosca. How to enable it? Wants to import some tsu files
Import subset option is disabled in tosca. How to enable it? Wants to import some tsu files I have tried it with multiple settings but still the tab is disabled
Should able to import the modules so that it will reduce efforts

If you are working in a multiuser repository, then your organization would have disabled the Import subset option. In this case, only the Admins have the access to Import subset.
